# How to send file to SharePoint from another application?

Tags: 2013, file-upload, file

I know how to upload files to SharePoint programmatically from `CSOM` but I need to do it from an application that I can't modify, this application only gives me the option of establishing a `url` where it sends the file, what `url` can I use? What code can I use in that `url` to deal with the file sent?

The application sends a xml file any time a survey is filled to a url, I want to include that xml file in a library and process the xml.

Comment: What you mean by establishing a URL? If its another application, without code how you will authenticate against SharePoint?

Comment: that can be another problem, I have thought about making a part of the site as anonymous accessed.

Comment: i have found a solution to create an application page that allows anonymous access,http://www.concurrency.com/sharepoint/allow-anonymous-access-to-sharepoint-application-pages-in-the-_layouts-directory/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is feasible out of the box.

One workaround that comes to my mind is creating an intermediary application or service. This service will have a method which can upload file to SharePoint.

Your application can then be configured to use the intermediary URL and pass the file information.

Comment: In this moment I have an ASP .net app that receives the file and then via csom it inserts the file, I would like to do it withing sharepoint.

Comment: You can convert that ASP.NET app into an application page in SharePoint and then use that.

Comment: Excuse me Amal, how can I do it? do you have any link where it is explained?

Comment: hi Amal, I have found a way to do it, http://www.concurrency.com/sharepoint/allow-anonymous-access-to-sharepoint-application-pages-in-the-_layouts-directory/